# Why all string literals in python evaluate to single quote?

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, python-3.x

Why all string literals in python evaluate to single quote?

```
'a', "a", """a"""
```

all evaluate to

```
'a'
```

in the inter-active shell.

Comment: Because these are the **same** literals. The quotes are not part of the string itself. The interpreter does not know how you entered the string.

Comment: See what `" 'a' "` gives you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make a distinction between the **content** of a string and **its representation**.

The literals `'a'`, `"a"` and `"""a"""` **all represent the same string**. So that means that after assigning that string, like:

```
t = "a"
```

Python no longer remembers how that string was entered. Furthermore for the string:

```
t = "a"+'b'
```

the resulting string is `'ab'`: there is simply no "original literal".

Now you query a variable (or an expression) in the terminal. The terminal will internally call the `repr(..)` method. So basically, you have written:

```
repr("a")
```

Now Python calls the `__repr__` method and that method inspects if there is a single quote in the string. If not, the string is represented with single quotes, otherwise it can be represented with double quotes. For instance:

```
>>> "'a'"
"'a'"
```

Comment: repr('a') does not produce 'a'?  also is "a" and 'b' still in memory in addition to new 'ab' literal?

Comment: @pypyad: `repr('a')` produces a string with **content `'a'`** and whether `'a'` and `'b'` remain in memory is a decision a Python interpreter makes. That is afaik not specified.

Answer (score 1):

Not all unicode literals are printed using `''`, case in point, if you mix these, Python will use the appropriate quotation to represent it:

```
>>> "'a'"
"'a'"
```

Choosing `''` over `""` (not `""" """` since those are less readable) for the case where no mixing of quotations is present is just a decision that was probably made very early on with no significant reasons behind it.

Python always chooses the `'` over `"` and those over `"""` when it can:

```
>>> """'a'"""
"'a'"
```

and there's no 'special' reasoning behind it.

Comment: Lol, we showed exactly the same counterexample :)